# If $f\in C^{\infty}$, $f$ is in Schwarz space iff $x^{\beta}\partial^{\alpha}f$ is bounded for $\forall \alpha, \beta$.

Tags: inequality, schwartz-space

The following prop. is quoted from Folland's Real Analysis. I understand every part of the proof except for 
$$|x^\beta|\leq(1+|x|)^N$$ 
and the very last inequality involving $\delta^{-1}$ in the line after "... and hence". Could you give me any idea of how to show the inequalities?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|x^\beta| = |x_1^{\beta_1}\cdots x_n^{\beta_n}| \le |x|^{\beta_1}\cdots |x|^{\beta_n} = |x|^{\beta_1 + \cdots \beta_n} = |x|^{|\beta|}.$$
As for your last question, it looks like that last term should be
$$2^N(1+\delta^{-1})\sum_{|\beta|\le N}|x^\beta|,$$
the reason being that $1,|x_1|^N,\dots , |x_n|^N$ are all included in the sum, but we don't know which is bigger, $1$ or $\delta^{-1}.$

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! I think $\delta^{-1}\geq 1$, so the last term can be just modified  $2^N\to 2^{N+1}$ as well.